# Can we reopen this question which used to have meaning-distorting grammar?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, review

The question [Effect of temperature and surrounding medium in the Cavendish experiment to measure the gravitational constant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427791/effect-of-temperature-and-surrounding-medium-in-the-cavendish-experiment-to-meas) was closed as 'unclear what you're asking', probably because earlier versions had messy grammar which made it difficult to understand. After an edit by the OP (which was probably a response to the 2 comments which mentioned that several parts weren't clear), I think I managed to put together the meaning, but the question was subsequently closed, much to my surprise.

I'm kind of confused about what happened, because I'm reasonably sure that a while back, before I decided to try to save it, I had cast a VTC, along with a few others (I think I could see that there were existing VTCs when I cast mine), but right now it says that a moderator closed it with a single vote.

Anyways, it looks like it's in a decent shape now, so can it be reopened? I've cast a reopen vote, but I don't know if that works for questions which haven't been modified since they were closed.

---

I had downvoted it earlier because the grammar impeded my understanding, but now that I've edited it and removed my downvote, it has a positive score (+1).

Comment: The question IMO remains rather unclear.  The OP asks for the effect of surface roughness, suggesting a connection between roughness and surface energy, which itself increases with temperature: I cannot understand how surface roughness or surface energy (of the sphere??) has anything to do with this.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Exactly, so the answer for that part is a straightforward "No, the surface roughness doesn't make a difference." Yes, it's a somewhat strange/random question, but it's not unclear (to me).